# Compile a .cpp file for an Arduino project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to start an Arduino project with Arduino IDE and I'd like to use external C++ code outside the .ino main file. In particular, I have the following file:

```
 arduino.ino <- main .ino file
 /HeartSensor
    HeartSensor.h
    HeartSensor.cpp
 /oledScreen
    oledScreen.h
    oledScreen.cpp
```

To import the two files in the folders I did the following:

```
 #include "HeartSensor/HeartSensor.h"
 #include "oledScreen/oledScreen.h"
```

The `HeartSensor.h` file, for example, contains the following code:

```
#ifndef HEARTSENSOR_H

#define WINDOWSIZE 50
#define HEARTSENSOR_H

#include <Arduino.h>

class HeartSensor{

private:
   float bpm = 0.0;
   int heartStatus = 0;
   bool receivingSignal = false;

   float ecgSignal[WINDOWSIZE];

public:

   // Constructors
   HeartSensor();
   ~HeartSensor();

   // Getters
   float getBPM(){ return bpm; };
   int getHeartStatus(){ return heartStatus; };
   bool getReceivingSignal(){ return receivingSignal; };

   // Setters
   void setBPM(const float& newBpm){ bpm = newBpm; };
   void setHeartStatus(const int& newHeartStatus){ heartStatus = newHeartStatus; };
   void setReceivingSignal(const bool& newReceivingSignal){ receivingSignal = newReceivingSignal; };

   void addSample(const float& newSample);

};

#endif
```

And the `HeartSensor.cpp` file contains the following code:

```
#include "HeartSensor.h"

HeartSensor::HeartSensor(){

}

void HeartSensor::addSample(const float& newSample){
   for(int i = 1; i < WINDOWSIZE-1; i++){
      ecgSignal[i-1] = ecgSignal[i];
}
   ecgSignal[WINDOWSIZE-1] = newSample;
}
```

If I try to access one the member functions in the header file, I have no problem. However, if I try to access a function that is in the cpp file like so:

```
HeartSensor* myHeartSensor;
myHeartSensor->addSample(0.0);
```

then the following error shows up:

```
arduino.ino:36: undefined reference to `HeartSensor::addSample(float const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you know how I can compile the cpp files?

Comment: don't put  source files into subfolders. the arduino builder doesn't compile files in subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lay out your project as:

```
arduino.ino <- main .ino file
/src
  /HeartSensor
    HeartSensor.h
    HeartSensor.cpp
  /oledScreen
    oledScreen.h
    oledScreen.cpp
```

To import the two files in the folders, do the following:

```
#include "src/HeartSensor/HeartSensor.h"
#include "src/oledScreen/oledScreen.h"
```